# How can you append an index number in a file name written by the Apache Camel file component?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have been trying to come up with a way to append an index number to a file written be Apache Camel file component.

Here is the use case: you have a file i.e. "input.xml" and this file is written repeatedly with different content into a folder by the Apache Camel "file" component. So the requirement is to append a counter so that each file with a colliding name contains a counter like i.e. "input-1.xml", "input-2.xml", "input-3.xml" and so on.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a perfect solution, but you could create a Camel bean with some state which remembers for a while which files have come through and does number these accordingly. My assumption is that the files which come through have unique names over time.

The bean code:

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Message;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Bean used to change the name of an output file with a counter.
 */
public class NameChangeBean {

    private static final Pattern NORMAL_FILE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(.+)(\\..+)");

    private Map<String, Integer> counter = new WeakHashMap<>();

    public void changeName(Exchange exchange) {
        Message in = exchange.getIn();
        String fileName = (String) in.getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME);
        Message out = exchange.getOut();
        out.setHeaders(in.getHeaders());
        if (fileName != null) {
            // Increase count by one or start at one
            Integer newNumber = counter.merge(fileName, 1, Integer::sum);
            Matcher matcher = NORMAL_FILE_PATTERN.matcher(fileName);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                out.setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, matcher.replaceFirst("$1-" + newNumber + "$2"));
            } else {
                out.setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, String.format("%s-%d", fileName, counter.merge(fileName, 1, Integer::sum)));
            }
        }
        out.setBody(in.getBody());
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use the bean in your route like so:

```
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.main.Main;

public class FileWriteChangeNameRoute {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Main main = new Main();

        System.out.println(javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.class);

        main.addRouteBuilder(new RouteBuilder() {

            public void configure() {
                from("file://D:/dev/playground/camel-activemq/src/data")
                        .bean(new NameChangeBean(), "changeName")
                        .to("file://D:/dev/playground/camel-activemq/src/data_out");
            }
        });

        main.run();
    }
}
```

This will produce on repeated files names numbered file versions, like:

```
input.xsd-1.xml
input.xsd-2.xml
input.xsd-3.xml
```